# Each single request on server for empty html page makes memoy increase. What could be causing this?

Tags: asp.net, memory-fragmentation

First of all, I am a junior developper and new to asp .Net

Our ASp.Net website should be put in production soon enough. Except that i realized **memory was** **increasing all the time, even if i refresh an empty html page.**
It starts with about 140 MO and can reach 1GO.
 I first thought of a memory leak but debugging tools seem to point out a memory fragmentaion. here is a result of perfmon indicators regarding .Net memory 
![perfmon:] https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7K1cn6Fma9oMHJmVV8tWGZJem8/edit?usp=sharing

Intel corei5
CLR: 4.0
VS2012
x64OS

Comment: 2 things you should know about is ViewState and GarbageCollection. **ViewState** - ASP.NET pages (by default) have a viewstate that is saved for each page. This ViewState expires after a period of time, based on many different things. **GarbageCollection** - Even though you release objects from your memory, .NET will not release the memory back to the OS until it needs to, or certain things occur. If you want more info, research those terms.

Answer (score 0):

Tank you very much steve, i had a look at viewstate. I know approximately what it is about.

The point is that if i press f5 to **reload a an empty page, memory increase by 1 Mo, which is far more than what viewstate string normally reach (??? if i can have confirmation)**.

If i do relaod for a normal page which gets data from the cache (the cache is about 120 Mo, everything is cached. it's an opinion website and user's opinions are being cached as well as products) memory increase by 10Mo.

It apperas to reach a stable point somewhat at 700Mo, sometimes more. 
Here is an ANTS profiler that seems to be confirming what i understood from the perfmon stats.

![enter image description here][1]

here the link to an ANTS result concerning memory prfiling: 
[enter link description here][1]
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7K1cn6Fma9oWDYzcHZLNkZYNkU/edit?usp=sharing

I'll try to follow this post :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/02/18/high-memory-part-5-fragmentation.aspx
(hope it s the good direction) and let you know about it.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

sorry the image of the previous post concerns the oppening of the website.

After a hundred refresh of the same page, i get this :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7K1cn6Fma9oWEU3Y0swWFZwSHc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry for closing the issue a year later i rely a lot on stackoverflow but don't interract much unfortunately)  : steve was absolutely right : .Net does not release the memory untill it's needed. It appeared to be a completely normal behavior, despite what i d been told at that time. Thanks steve